# Template classes using each other gives ambiguity error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, forward-declaration

I have two template classes A and B in the same header file as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class FirstClass {

public:
    bool convert(const FirstClass<T>& f){...}
    bool convert(const SecondClass<T>& s){...}

};


template <typename T>
class SecondClass {

public:
    bool convert(const FirstClass<T>& f){...}
    bool convert(const SecondClass<T>& s){...}

};
```

In order to resolve any unknown class errors, I tried adding a forward declaration:

```
template <typename T> class SecondClass ; //adding this to the beginning of the file
```

I get the following error:

```
2 overloads have similar conversions 
could be 'bool FirstClass<T>::convert(const FirstClass<T>& )' 
or
could be 'bool FirstClass<T>::convert(const SecondClass<T>& )'
while trying to match the argument list '(FirstClass<T>)'
note: qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity
```

I am assuming this is because I am using a forward declared class. Other than moving the implementation to Cpp files( which I have been told is cumbersome), is there any other efficient solution to this?

I am using VisualStudio 2010 on Windows 7

Comment: What is the line of code that the error is being raised for?

Comment: Why do you need to convert from `FirstClass<T>` to `FirstClass<T>` ?

Comment: I guess that's not the whole code, at least there is no call to `convert()` that would trigger such an ambiguity error. Please try to give us a minimal code example that gives the exact same error when *we* compile it. Without that code one would need a crystal ball to see what's the problem, and mine has been broken for a while now...

Comment: @Arne Yes. I am working on that. The above is not the actual code. I will post a working sample soon.

Comment: The code as posted compiles. You error is somewhere else. Without the code that causes the error this question is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the forward declarations before you define any of the two classes.

```
#include <iostream>    

template<typename> class FirstClass;
template<typename> class SecondClass;

template <typename T>
class FirstClass {

public:
    bool convert(const FirstClass<T>& f) { std::cout << "f2f\n"; }
    bool convert(const SecondClass<T>& s){ std::cout << "f2s\n"; }

};


template <typename T>
class SecondClass {

public:
    bool convert(const FirstClass<T>& f){ std::cout << "s2f\n"; }
    bool convert(const SecondClass<T>& s){ std::cout << "s2s\n"; }

};

int main()
{
    FirstClass<int> f;
    SecondClass<int> s;

    f.convert(f);
    f.convert(s);
    s.convert(f);
    s.convert(s);        
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IBYghc)